# The linear heat eqaution with potential $V\in L_{t,x}^{\frac{n+2}2}$ is well-posed for initial data in $L^p$ for any $p\in(1,\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, heat-equation, perturbation-theory

> Consider the linear heat equation with potential
> $$u_t-\Delta u-V(x,t)u=0\qquad \text{in }\ \  \mathbb R^n\times[0,\infty),$$
> where $V\in L_{t,x}^{\frac{n+2}2}$. Show that this equation is well-posed for initial data in $L^p$ for any $p\in(1,\infty)$.

This question comes from [Hao Jia and Vladimir Sverak's paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002212361500138X), page 3739, where the authors claim the statement and indicate that it can be proved “by usual perturbation arguments”. I don't know what is the "usual arguments". So I'm asking here in which book or material I can learn this sort of thing.

Any help or useful reference will be appreciated.

Comment: You have a formula for the solution to the inhomogeneous heat equation. Plug $V(x,t)u$ into that formula. Now your equation became a fixed-point one. And now you can try solving it via the fixed point theorem.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks for your comment. I've already had a proof, using exactly the same idea as yours. But I'm just lazy to typeset it because it is relatively long. Anyway, thank you. Your comment will help many other users here.

Comment: You're welcome. I have also been lazy, I just wrote a two line comment instead of a full solution. :-)